# Loop through javascript object and get specific value from given key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function within my project that loops through a team of people and adds them to an object:

```
var trainingTeam = {};
...
$(data).find('trainingTeam>member').each(function() {
   trainingTeam = {first: tFirst, last: tLast, ntid: tNTID, empID: tEmp, role: tRole}; 
}
```

I am now trying to loop over that object and get specific values from it.

```
$.each(trainingTeam, function(x, y) {
   alert('Team Member : ' y.first + ' ' + y.last)
});
```

This returns undefined with both `X` and `Y` so I am obviously doing something wrong.

Am I close?

**UPDATE**

Solved by changing the var to `var trainingTeam = []`

I then pushed the object to the array in the loop :

`trainingTeam.push({first: tFirst, last: tLast, ntid: tNTID, empID: tEmp, role: tRole});`

Answer (score 0):

`X` and `Y`, are `key` and `value`.

So

```
$.each(trainingTeam, function(x, y) {
   //here y is 'first' and x is 'tFirst' 

});
```

Comment: it it were 2 dimensional that would work but what If I want to get the ROLE from the object? I need to be able to specify what value I want given the key.

Comment: @SBB which object is 2 dimensional ?

Comment: I feel like your answer would be appropriate for an Array `Key/Value' but in my case, my keys are defined and I need to be able to access them by name and get its value.